# nmea_gps_driver in launch file

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I am creating a launch file for my robot, I am trying to run the nmea_gps_driver in my launchfile this is what I have so far:

```
<launch> 
<node pkg="nmea_gps_driver" name="nmea_gps_launch" type="nmea_gps_driver.py" args="_port:=/dev/ttyUSB0 _baud:=9600"/>
</launch>
```

But when I launch it I get the following message and then error:

```
 File "/opt/ros/groovy/stacks/nmea_gps_driver/src/nmea_gps_driver.py", line 112, in <module>
    data = GPS.readline()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/serial/serialposix.py", line 449, in read
    buf = os.read(self.fd, size-len(read))
OSError: [Errno 11] Resource temporarily unavailable

[nmea_gps_launch-27] process has died [pid 17480, exit code 1, cmd /opt/ros/groovy/stacks/nmea_gps_driver/src/nmea_gps_driver.py _port:=/dev/ttyUSB0 _baud:=9600 __name:=nmea_gps_launch __log:=/home/alex/.ros/log/60c20282-e895-11e2-8751-6036dd23d944/nmea_gps_launch-27.log].
log file: /home/alex/.ros/log/60c20282-e895-11e2-8751-6036dd23d944/nmea_gps_launch-27*.log
```

It is definatly a 9600 Baud Reciever and is showing up as /dev/ttyUSB0.

The following command works perfectly in the terminal and the GPS publishes data.

```
$ rosrun nmea_gps_driver nmea_gps_driver.py _port:=/dev/ttyUSB0 _baud:=9600
```

Any Ideas?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/66892/nmea_gps_driver-in-launch-file/) by [clungzta](https://answers.ros.org/users/5356/clungzta/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2013-07-09

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [sai](https://answers.ros.org/users/2967/sai/) on 2013-07-09**:
try other GPS pkg, may be gps_common, utm_odometry_node

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If running the command with `rosrun` as in your command line example works fine, I do not see why your `roslaunch` fails (provided both are executed by the same user in the same environment, otherwise there might be some problem with the device file permissions, or even the gps might associated to a different `/dev/ttyXXX`).

However, you may try setting the parameters using [`<param>` tags](http://wiki.ros.org/roslaunch/XML/param) inside the [`<node>` tags](http://wiki.ros.org/roslaunch/XML/node) (which IMHO is a better style anyway):

```
<launch> 
  <node pkg="nmea_gps_driver" type="nmea_gps_driver.py" name="nmea_gps_launch">
    <param name="port" type="str" value="/dev/ttyUSB0" />
    <param name="baud" type="int" value="9600" />
  </node>
</launch>
```

Maybe that makes a difference.

---

Originally posted by [joanpau](https://answers.ros.org/users/893/joanpau/) with karma: 191 on 2013-12-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0